# How to test that two objects are not equal using testthat in R

Tags: r, automated-tests, testthat

How can I test that two objects in R are not equal? There is no complement to the expect_equal() function, such as expect_not_equal().

The answer didn't pop into my head at first, so I tried searching online however most just made it needlessly complicated (at least for the purposes of writing automated tests) with base R or directly using compare() commands etc.

Comment: `expect_false(identical(obj1, obj2))`?

Comment: Yep that works too

Answer (score 0):

Simply do `expect_failure(expect_equal(object1, object2))`, or the same for expect_identical and I guess anything else you want to check failure for.

A simple solution but at least for me I missed it at first, and then Google searches just confused me more.